# NextJS and localstorage - How to use it correctly?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, build, local-storage, i18next

```
"use client";
import { usePathname } from "next/navigation";
import Image from "next/image";
import i18n from "../../app/i18n";
import styles from "./styles.module.css";
import BR from "../../assets/images/official-pics/flags/BR.svg";
import FR from "../../assets/images/official-pics/flags/FR.svg";
import GE from "../../assets/images/official-pics/flags/GE.svg";
import SP from "../../assets/images/official-pics/flags/SP.svg";
import US from "../../assets/images/official-pics/flags/US.svg";
import BRAdvLogo from "../../assets/images/official-pics/bradv/logobradv.png";
import Socials from "../Socials";
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";
import { useLocalStorage } from "../../Hooks/useLocalStorage";

export default function Navbar() {
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  const pathname = usePathname();

  //code below to load last language used
  useLocalStorage("i18nextLng", "pt");

  const handleChangeLanguage = (value: string) => {
    i18n.changeLanguage(value);
  };

  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <div className={styles.content}>
        <Image src={BRAdvLogo} alt="logo" width={64} height={64} />
        <Socials />

        <div className={styles.nav}>
          <a className={pathname === "/" ? styles.active : ""} href="/">
            {t("navbar.home")}
          </a>
          <a
            className={pathname === "/quem-somos" ? styles.active : ""}
            href="/quem-somos"
          >
            {t("navbar.about")}
          </a>
          <a
            className={pathname === "/contato" ? styles.active : ""}
            href="/contato"
          >
            {t("navbar.contact")}
          </a>
          <a className={pathname === "/blog" ? styles.active : ""} href="/blog">
            {t("navbar.blog")}
          </a>
        </div>

        <div className={styles.available__languages}>
          <div>
            <button onClick={() => handleChangeLanguage("pt")}>
              <Image src={BR} alt="Brazil" />
            </button>
            <button onClick={() => handleChangeLanguage("en")}>
              <Image src={US} alt="United States" />
            </button>
            <button onClick={() => handleChangeLanguage("fr")}>
              <Image src={FR} alt="France" />
            </button>
            <button onClick={() => handleChangeLanguage("de")}>
              <Image src={GE} alt="Germany" />
            </button>
            <button onClick={() => handleChangeLanguage("es")}>
              <Image src={SP} alt="Spain" />
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

So I have the code above, for a Navbar component, which changes language using i18next. It`s a NextJS project. This works on dev mode, but when I try building it, it says **localStorage is not defined** (even using a hook like the code above or calling directly `localStorage.getItem('i18nextLng')`).

I know that localStorage is a browser variable, and server side rendered pages don`t have access to it, but this component is client side rendered, so I have no idea why it does not work.

Can`t seem to find a fix!

Answer (score 2):

Reasons for the error are:

- Next.js executes server-side rendering(SSR) before client-side rendering(CSR).
- As you mentioned, global objects such as `window` or `document` may not be accessed by Next.js in SSR.
- `window` only exists in the client-side. Therefore, `localStorage` may not be accessed before `window` is defined.

SOLUTION 1 :`typeof window !== 'undefined'`

```
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
   const item = localStorage.getItem('key)
}
```

Above code waits for client to get mounted and then accesses localStorage. If no `window` is referenced, it returns undefined. Again, we need for localStorage to be defined before accessing it.

SOLUTION 2: `useEffect`

```
useEffect(() => {
  const item = localStorage.getItem('key')
}, [])
```

`useEffect` hook is executed in client-side rendering, so it is not executed while Next.js SSR. => We can safely access localStorage after it is defined.

Good luck!

Comment: Perfect, I saw some answers like that but couldn't really implent it. But, after all, I did not need it, the main problem actually was that the main HTML had a lang='en' as default. Don't know if it is correct, but when I removed the default lang, I was able to change languages and keep them whenever pages changed.