Lazy initialization problem with local storage in Next js
I've encountered a problem referencing window; the error is described as:

ReferenceError: window is not defined

I'm trying to set a local storage value by using lazy initialization:
const [colors, setColors] = useState(()=>{
  if(window){
    return localStorage.getItem("_appColor") ?
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("_appColor")) : null
  }else {
    return null
  }
});

I tried adding a check for window object in the code above, but I still get the reference error.
I didn't use useEffect because it causes the color object to be undefined initially and then it will get the data from local storage.
How to use Lazy initialization for useState hook inside of client components to get local storage data without encountering reference error?

consider putting the window and localstorage access in a useeffect

@evolutionxbox I explained why I can't do that and despite of that you flag my question as duplicate? I even have a check for local storage. you didn't even read my question

if (typeof window !== "undefined") from the duplicate didn't work for you…?

Can you more clearly specify how it "won't work"? It should get rid of the immediate cause of the error, thus eliminating the specific error message, no? What secondary "doesn't work" are you seeing after this? — I have no experience with React specifically, so I probably won't be able to provide a React/next specific solution. But even for others, it'd help if you clarify what you tried and why it didn't work as much as possible.

Sorry for seming like I didn't read the question. You're running into a limitation with nextjs. You don't have many options accessing localstorage https://stackoverflow.com/a/77328300/989920

Next time, believe in the system, will ya?

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not fill your post with repeated or nonsense content as a way to work around the quality filter. If the system prompts you to add additional explanation to your post, then do so. Don't attempt to bypass the warning. This is considered an abuse of the system, and may lead to your post being summarily removed and/or your account being sanctioned. Take the [tour], read up on [ask] and then [edit] your post with more details.

In Next.js, you can't access window during SSR. To work around this you can use useEffect, but you don't want to do that since the initial value is not defined initially. To solve this problem, you can use useLayoutEffect. useLayoutEffect is designed to run code before rendering a component, defining the initial value of a color. I provide updated code for it.
const [colors, setColors] = useState(null);

useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if(window) {
        setColors(localStorage.getItem("_appColor") ?
        JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("_appColor")) : null)
    } else {
        setColors(null) 
    }
}, []);

You can get more information about the useLayoutEffect here

useLayoutEffect usage is discouraged
https://react.dev/reference/react/useLayoutEffect
